# how to fix rendering problems in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, render

I accidentally miss-clicked in the button 'API Version for Preview' and now i have render problems in all my projects

[this is how i see the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylsh.png)

And i get the following errors:

One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes

Missing classes

Render problem

Failed to instantiate one or more classes

My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ang.alfredo.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: kindly post your xml file too.

Comment: add your xml code

Comment: @AndroidTeam i have added it

Comment: android studio goto file option and select invalid and restart option

Comment: because your xml code right

Comment: you used android studio 3.2.1

Comment: @AndroidTeam yes im using 3.2.1, and 'Invalidate caches & restart' dont worked

Comment: you make single layout file check any other layout file not miss give layout_width and height property.

Comment: change this dependency  `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` from  any of your existing project which is rendering properly.

Answer (score -1):

Sync project again.By pressing **"Sync Project with gradle"**.

If the issue stays same try to **'Invalidate caches & restart'**.You can find it in **"File"**
 menu.

Comment: Try this way .Clean --> Rebuilt --> Sync